# Dynamic NSTouchBar items

Tags: swift, appkit, nstouchbar

I'm wondering if it's possible to dynamically create `NSTouchBar` items. In my app I've got a dataSource protocol to fill the contents of an `NSTableViewController`. I'd like to use this protocol to also fill the touchBar with the same options.

This is the protocol I'm using.

```
protocol RestaurantsViewControllerDelegate {
    func numberOfRestaurants(in restaurantsViewController: RestaurantsViewController) -> Int
    func restaurantsViewController(_ restaurantsViewController: RestaurantsViewController, restaurantAtIndex index: Int) -> Restaurant
    func restaurantsViewController(_ restaurantsViewController: RestaurantsViewController, didSelectRestaurant restaurant: Restaurant)
}
```

The only code that I've found only, though, suggests that I have to manually create each button, like so.

```
@available(OSX 10.12.1, *)
extension NSTouchBarItem.Identifier {
    static let restaurant = NSTouchBarItem.Identifier("my.custom.identifier")
}

extension RestaurantsViewController: NSTouchBarDelegate {
    override func makeTouchBar() -> NSTouchBar? {
        let touchBar = NSTouchBar()
        touchBar.delegate = self
        touchBar.defaultItemIdentifiers = [.restaurant]
        return touchBar
    }

    func touchBar(_ touchBar: NSTouchBar, makeItemForIdentifier identifier: NSTouchBarItem.Identifier) -> NSTouchBarItem? {
        switch identifier {

        case NSTouchBarItem.Identifier.restaurant:
            let item = NSCustomTouchBarItem(identifier: identifier)
            item.view = NSButton(title: "This is a restaurant", target: nil, action: nil)
            return item
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to what I'd like to do?

Answer (score 0):

`NSTouchBarItem.Identifier` can be based on any string, including dynamic ones based on some identifier of the `Restaurant` object. You could set the `defaultItemIdentifiers` to that array of dynamically generated identifiers, and then `touchBar(_:,makeItemForIdentifier:)` will be called for each of those identifiers (which you can then dynmically create a button or otherwise for each of those identifiers).

Another alternative is to use [`NSScrubber`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscrubber). This could be a single item in the Touch Bar, but then it has a DataSource that could be used to populate it based on your Restaurant data source.